# Mongoose doesn't respect ref schema definition upon document update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `ref` type field in one of my schemas:

```
someField: {
  type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'SomeModel'
}
```

When I try to create a new document with a bogus `someField` (the one that doesn't exist), Mongoose complains and says no, get that shit out of here. But when I try to update an existing document with a bogus `someField`, it says nothing, and lets it through. Am I missing something, or does this look like a bug?

Answer (score 1):

After an extensive search, I found a solution. Both, `findOneAndUpdate()` and `updateMany()`, expect an additional options parameter. Passing `runValidators: true` fixes the issue:

```
.findOneAndUpdate( // Or `.updateMany(`
  conditions,
  data,
  {
    runValidators: true
  }
)
```

I wish this was somehow mentioned in the Mongoose schema documentation.

Comment: I faced the same issue. And this solved my problem. Thank you.